# Attempts at writing the Terraform code for AWS KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform, amazon-kms

> **Goal :**
>
> > I am trying to create the following things A terraform template to
> >     create KMS keys This template should create the key and two IAM roles.
> >     The roles would be  one for admin functions and  one that allows
> >     encrypt/decrypt I have written the following code

Am I doing the correct thing to achieve my goal?

```
provider "aws"
{
access_key = "*****************"
secret_key = "4ZJaLh***********"
region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "test_key" {
  description             = "KMS Test key"
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "alias" {
  name          = "alias/test_key"
  target_key_id = "${aws_kms_key.test_key.key_id}"
}

#IAM Role and Policy

resource "aws_iam_policy" "kms_user_policy" {
    name = "KMS-User-Policy"
    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:ReEncryptTo",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:ReEncryptFrom"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "kms_user_role" {
  name = "kms_user_role"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
               "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  name       = "test-attachment"
  roles      = ["${aws_iam_role.kms_user_role.name}"]
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.kms_user_policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you confused about and having trouble with?

Comment: What I want to do is to write a terraform script to create a KMS key, two roles(admin and User), I am confused on how to create a role and relate it to the key?

Comment: And what have you tried? Can you edit the question to show attempts at writing the Terraform code?

Comment: Following is the code I've written 
I want to add roles to this key
`provider "aws"
{
access_key = "*****************"
secret_key = "4ZJaLh***********"
region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "Test_key" {
  description             = "KMS Test key"
}
resource "aws_kms_alias" "alias" {
  name          = "alias/test_key"
  target_key_id = "${aws_kms_key.test_key.key_id}"
}`

Comment: You should edit your question to show code instead of adding it as a comment. Also you need to show what you are doing with your IAM roles.